# Android Studio wear app installation fails

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, wear-os

So I've got a project with a mobile and a wear part. Actually, it's the default Basic Activity and Basic Wear Activity project, targeting API 21 on the phone and the latest 7.1.1 for watches. My watch (OG LG Urbane on AW2.0) is plugged in with ADB debugging enabled.

The watch shows up in the list of ADB devices, but when I try to run the 'wear' project on it, I get the following error:

```
device '506KPQJ0130548' not found com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device '506KPQJ0130548' not found at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:862)   at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:451)    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.uploadApk(SplitApkInstaller.java:152)   at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:78)  at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:904)   at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask$SplitApkInstaller.installApp(SplitApkDeployTask.java:117)    at com.android.tools.idea.run.RetryingInstaller.install(RetryingInstaller.java:86)  at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask.perform(SplitApkDeployTask.java:86)  at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:120)   at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.Core... (a minute ago)
```

The watch then disappears from ADB for a few seconds, like something crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what it turns out is that there is some incompatibility with USB 3.0 in the cable, charger or watch. When I use another port, there's no problem.

That's really annoying though, all my computer's USB 2 ports are on the back so my watch has to sit in a very awkward location where I can't really test it without going under the desk. You wouldn't think that would be an issue with a modern device, but probably LG's fault.